# Text substitution (reading from file and saving to the same file) on linux with sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed, command-line-interface

I want to read the file "teste", make some "find&replace" and overwrite "teste" with the results. The closer i got till now is:

```
$cat teste
I have to find something
This is hard to find...
Find it wright now!

$sed -n 's/find/replace/w teste1' teste

$cat teste1
I have to replace something
This is hard to replace...
```

If I try to save to the same file like this:

```
$sed -n 's/find/replace/w teste' teste
```

or:

```
$sed -n 's/find/replace/' teste > teste
```

The result will be a blank file...

I know I am missing something very stupid but any help will be welcome.

---

UPDATE: Based on the tips given by the folks and this link: http://idolinux.blogspot.com/2008/08/sed-in-place-edit.html here's my updated code:

```
sed -i -e 's/find/replace/g' teste
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

On Linux, `sed -i` is the way to go.  `sed` isn't actually designed for in-place editing, though; historically, it's a filter, a program which edits a stream of data in a pipeline, and for this usage you would need to write to a temporary file and then rename it.

The reason you get an empty file is that the shell opens (and truncates) the file before running the command.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would "ed" be more apropriate to in-place editing instead of "sed"?

Comment: Yes and no; `ed` is better for in-place editing but not very convenient for use in scripts, which is why `sed` has grown a nonstandard (per POSIX) `-i` option.

Comment: So for in-place find&replace editing the best in Linux is "sed". Is it correct to say that?

Comment: Yes.  Or `perl -i` which does much the same thing (and was the inspiration for adding `-i` to `sed`) but is rather heavier.

Answer (score 25):

You want: `sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' file`

Comment: In my case I needed the -e prefix for the expression

Answer (score 8):

You want to use "sed -i".  This updates in place.

Answer (score 2):

In-place editing with perl

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/foo/bar/g;' file.txt
```

or

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/foo/bar/g;' files*
```

for many files

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you use `-i` flag, `sed` will copy the original line you edit.

So this might be a better way:

```
sed -i -e 's/old/new/g' -e '/new/d' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing worked for me on **MacOS**, but after some research I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283407/can-sed-save-its-output-to-a-file).

So the following works on **MacOS**:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/find/replace/g' teste
```

However, on **Linux** distro's (in my pipelines) the following worked and the above command throwed errors:

```
sed -i -e 's/find/replace/g' teste
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ed` solution is:

```
ed teste <<END
1,$s/find/replace/g
w
q
END
```

Or without the heredoc

```
printf "%s\n" '1,$s/find/replace/g' w q | ed teste
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful **sponge** command.

**sponge** soaks up all its input before opening the output file.

```
$cat test.txt | sed 's/find/replace/w' | sponge test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another command appropriate for your task available in Unix and Plan9 would be tee

```
sed 's/find/replace/'<file | tee file
```